# How do I construct the polynomial sequence for my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

For an assignment, I have created a class to represent a polynomial by storing a list with its coefficients, as a data member of the class.

- The first element of the list (index 0) represents the constant;
- the second (index 1) represents the coefficient of the x term, and so on,
- with each next element representing the coefficient of the next power of the polynomial.

Though I am having trouble creating the last function for it `"polySequence"`:

> A function polySequence which takes a start, end, and step, and returns a generator. The generator will evaluate the polynomial for the value
>   start, then start + end, and so on, up to end and yield these values one
>   at a time. If no step is given, a step of 1 should be used (similar to the
>   range method). As an example, if p represents the polynomial 2x + 1
>   (coefficient list [1,2]), the code

```
for val in p.polySequence(0,5):
    print(val)
```

should print the values 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 on separate lines.

Here is my implementation of the Polysequence at the bottom:

Comment: Where is the Polynomial.polySequence() is called/referenced in this code?

Comment: The polySequence function is at the bottom of the code

Comment: Is this what you were asking?

Comment: If not, I think what you may mean is that I was trying to test my code in the python shell ```"Polynomial.polySequence()"```, with whatever parameters and thats how I got that error. But I had mentioned that I have trouble in how to test my code when using classes. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks you've passed only the first argument to polySequence function. You should pass all declared arguments (start, stop and step):

```
p = Polynomial(1, 2)
for val in p.polySequence(0, 5, 1):
    print(val)
```

Comment: No it did not work. I think it was both accessing the method, and the written code for the function. I had mentioned that I was not sure if I had written that specific function’s code correctly. Because now it gives me an unexpected result. I will edit the question and put what the result says

Comment: It's supposed to be like the example the prompt gave

Comment: Please see my new question

Answer (score 0):

The way you are accessing polySequence method is not right. Only static or class methods are called like that. You need to instantiate the class and then call the polySequence method. for example

```
obj = Polynomial(1, 2)
for res in obj.polySequence(0, 5, 1):
    print(res)
```

Also I can see the **start** variable is always overwritten in your code inside polySequence method. If it is so why **start** argument in the method?

Comment: Oh I see! I assume the way how I was trying to access it was incorrect then. I thought the code for my polySequence function was written incorrectly? And could you clarify what you meant by my ``` start ``` argument is “always overwritten” ?

Comment: What if you remove the start argument from method definition, will polySequence method  work as intended?

Comment: Um, I’m not sure? I was just trying to follow what my professor said because he wrote that prompt and that’s just how he said it up. But I definitely see what you are saying though. Because from my understanding, I wasn’t even sure if I had written the polySequence function correctly based on the requirements he gave in the prompt? Like for example, I think I may have to initiative “step=1” in the parameter, if “step is not given”. Does my code qualify for what the prompt asked? For the polySequence

Comment: start variable is always assigned value from coefficient list so passing it as argument does not serve any purpose. That is what I wanted to convey. Rest is yours decision. Your actual problem is the way you were accessing the method. I hope I have pointed out the right thing. consider this solution if it really solves your actual problem.

Comment: No it did not work. I think it was both accessing the method, and the written code for the function. I had mentioned that I was not sure if I had written that specific function’s code correctly. Because now it gives me an unexpected result. I will edit the question and put what the result says. Also, I think the start variable, was supposed to be used to call my eval function

Comment: It's supposed to be like the example the prompt gave

Comment: I put it in a new question